# Cannot connect to the BD in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Not sure where my php is wrong:

```
class BDConnection{


        private $_bdname;
        private $_root;
        private $_address;

        function __construct(){

            $this->$_address = 'localhost';
            $this->$_bdname = 'Vuelos';
            $this->$_root   = 'root';
        }

        static function link($con){

            $connection = mysqli_connect("$con->_address","$con->_root","","$con->_bdname") or die("Problemas con la conexión");

            return $connection;
        }

        static function close($con){

            mysqli_close($con);

            return;
        }


    }
```

The execution part:

```
$connection = new BDConnection();
$conexion= BDConnection::link($connection);
```

And the error that is giving me:

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: _address in C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerPHP\PruebaFormularios\BDConnection.php on line 12

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerPHP\PruebaFormularios\BDConnection.php:12 
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerPHP\PruebaFormularios\PasajeroVueloconForm.php(31): BDConnection->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerPHP\PruebaFormularios\BDConnection.php on line 12
```

Not sure why it's not recognizing $_address and what can be wrong

Comment: you're mixing static and "dynamic" calls.

Comment: I'm new to PHP could you please explain?

Comment: In your __construct function change `$this->$_address = 'localhost'` to `$this->_address = 'localhost'` (remove $ from $_address). Same for other 2 lines.

Comment: Wow thanks!!! , i feel stupid now.(lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots and lots of cargo-cult programming:

```
    function __construct(){

        $this->$_address = 'localhost';
        $this->$_bdname = 'Vuelos';
        $this->$_root   = 'root';
               ^^^^^^
```

`$_root` is undefined at that point, so you're effectively trying to do `$this->null = 'root'`. All of those `$_` should be **JUST** `_`.

All of the `"$con->_address"`-type variable uses are also redundant. There is NO point in doing `"$var"`, simply use `$var`.

Comment: All of the "$con->_address"-type variable uses are also redundant. There is NO point in doing "$var", simply use $var.

Did not catch this, could you give me the example (i started php this week)

Comment: like said, I stuff a variable into a `"..."` by itself, so you literally have `"$var"` is pointless. It just makes php build ANOTHER string out of the string you have already. about the only time it would matter is if `$var` is an object that implements __toString(), and that's not the case here.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!

Comment: And the whole `$con` business is pointless as well. You're defining an object. The whole point of objects is to encapsulate functions and data for those functions together in a single place. Passing around your object as arguments to those function defeats the purpose of having an object in the first place. if you made them NON-static, then you could do `$connection->link()` directly, and have direct `$this->_address` access within the link method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class BDConnection{
    private $dbname;
    private $username;
    private $host;

    function __construct(Array $credentials){

        $this->host = $credentials['HOST'];
        $this->dbname = $credentials['DB_NAME'];
        $this->username   = $credentials['USERNAME'];
    }

    static function link(BDConnection $connection){

        return mysqli_connect($connection->host,$connection->username,"",$connection->dbname) or die("Problemas con la conexión");
    }

    static function close(BDConnection $con){

        mysqli_close($con);

        return;
    }


}
$credentials = ['HOST'=>'localhost','DB_NAME'=>'songs','USERNAME'=>'root'];
$connection = new BDConnection($credentials);
$conexion= BDConnection::link($connection);
```

Comment: My intention  was not to have  the credentials on the main class but to have it encapsulated on the BDConnection class. Why should i create the $credentials array?

Comment: Off course, you can hardcode it to __construct , like before, but i prefer to inject credentials from outside, so this is not good idea to write credentials right in __construct.

I would recommend to read about Dependency Injection, i would use Pimple https://www.sitepoint.com/dependency-injection-with-pimple/